# Cannot find record to be updated when creating record in custom workflow assembly

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, workflow, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I haven't really had to create records in code before but found some code that think should work:

```
Entity CustAssetOperatingHours = new Entity("prefix_customerassetoperatinghourshistory");
CustAssetOperatingHours["prefix_name"] = sibling["prefix_name"].ToString();
Guid custAssetOperatingHoursId = service.Create(CustAssetOperatingHours);
```

Its failing at `service.Create(CustAssetOperatingHours);`

With the following biz process error:

> Cannot find record to be updated

An extra eye would help.

Comment: Check if you have plugin/workflow on create of this entity? That code expecting something may throw this error up here..

Comment: Yes, the workflow executes onCreate.  This has sibling records and when it creates a child, it creates other sibling records.  What it is a parameter from a dictionary that I passed into the method which I verified in trace logs is there.  I made sure the context.depth is not > 1 so can't loop again.  Because this is a N:1 relationship, must I declare relationship first?

Comment: if you are trying to set the created record to the sibling using onCreate Workflow, check if the sibling records are created already as their creation may be async so when you try to update the parent lookup they are not yet create. if you are sure they are created try to use tracing service to trace all the values this might give you a hint about why this creation fails.

Answer (score 0):

according with comments, you could add a condition to workflow triggered at the creation evaluating if the lookup attribute (which creates the relation to the expected record) has data, if not, continue with the execution

Hope it helps - M.Acosta.D